# C# - How to get all rows back in dataGridView after reopening form ,but I applied filter before closing form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, ado.net

I am working on windows form application.

It contains two form MainForm - Test and childForm - Search

In Testform, I created dataTable "dt". And  Search form contains datagridview control.. I applied two filters for datagridview column -

1st - update SrNo column according to serial number

2nd - get rows in between FROM and TO date.

My main question is, When I first time load Search form, It gives me all data rows present in datatable..But when I applied filter and close form and then again reopen the Search form, It gives me filtered rows, not all rows.
Please help me to solve this issue. thanks in advance

Code for Test Form:

```
  private void SearchToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchTest Search = new SearchTest(dt);
        Search.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Code for SearchTest Class:

```
 public partial class SearchTest : Form
{
    public SearchTest(DataTable TestData)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = TestData;
        this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["SrNo"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }


    private void btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = dateTimePicker1.Text;
        string str1 = dateTimePicker2.Text;

        DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
        DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(str1, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
        string dtFilter = string.Format("[Date] >= '{0} ' AND [Date] <= '{1} '", date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), date1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = dtFilter;
    }

    private void tb_SearchSrNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb_SearchSrNo.Text) ?
                "SrNo IS NOT NULL" :
                String.Format("SrNo LIKE '{0}%' OR SrNo LIKE '{1}%' OR SrNo LIKE '{2}%' OR SrNo LIKE '{3}%'", tb_SearchSrNo.Text, tb_SearchSrNo.Text, tb_SearchSrNo.Text, tb_SearchSrNo.Text);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void SearchTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTable` is reference type and when you pass it to the form, changes which you make on the object are permanent.

Currently you are passing a `DataTable` to the form, then you applied a filter on that instance and then closed the form. It means the filter is still there in the `DataTable` instance, so the next time that you pass the same `DataTable` instance to the form, it has filter.

To solve the problem, you can simply set `Filter` to `String.Empty` or use a `BinsingSource` as data source of the `DataGridView` and set `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`.

For example after the `ShowDialog` put `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "";` and it will solve the problem.

Comment: I applied above but still not getting the result

Comment: After the `ShowDialog` put `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "";` It will solve the problem. Otherwise you need to show how you create and where dt is stored.

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei - Thank you so much. dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = ""; thats I was missing. My problem is resolved.

Comment: That's great! It's exactly what I described in the answer ;) You're welcome :)